# z-index not functioning correctly

Tags: html, css, z-index

For some reason, my z-indexs are not working.

```
¬ .levelThree pos:ab
      ¬ .internalMenu > ul > li pos:rel
           ¬ .levelFive pos:ab
```

.levelFive should be in front of all other elements.

[Js Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dCYdw/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give **z-index** to your **li.active**. Write like this:

```
.internalMenu > ul > li, .levelThree > ul > li.active{
    z-index:10;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/dCYdw/10/

Answer (score 0):

If you want level five to appear in front of all other elements, you don't even need to set z-indicies, as the natural stacking order will have children on top of parents.

For the record though, I do see this (shortened), which is wrong:

```
.levelFive { z-index: 2; }
.levelThree li { z-index: 3; }
```

That explicitly says that all li's in .levelThree (including the parents of .levelFive) have a higher z-index than anything in levelFive.

So, your title is incorrect, z-index does function correctly, you have no coded it correctly, however.

Comment: agree with all your comments. Although i need the z-indexs on levelThree, hence me using it. But spot on with .levelThree li having a z-index. I didn't spot this.